# Upload file with SCP bash script

Tags: bash

I need bash script to upload file with SCP. How I can do that in script, I want to call that script fromother program. ( I know to do that with EXPECT but I need plain bash script). Can anybody help ?

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063481/upload-file-with-scp-bash-script).

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

scp /path/to/source destination.machine.address:/path/to/destination
```

Is what you want? I'm not entirely sure what your problem is. Full `scp` instructions can be accessed with `man scp` in your terminal. If you're calling it from a script, you will probably want to [set up public/private key authentication](http://blogs.translucentcode.org/mick/archives/000230.html) so you don't need to enter the password (entering the password from the calling program is doable, but a faff).